In Early Modern English, is it common to use “if thou do something”, or “if he do something”?
In the sentence patterns mentioned above, the predicates are uninflected. But in current English, such subjunctive usage only appears in the copula be (I assume). Eg., "whether it be" is a counterpart of "whether it is". But are there any differences between them?
Excerpts from EME:



The heart thou canst not all subdue
Must still resist,
if thou delay!
—How clear she shines (1846) by Emily Bronte




And therefore, if a man write little, he had need have a great memory.
—Of studies by Francis Bacon



Thou is the singular form of you, and I find its verb usually inflected with -est in simple present tense. But in the instances mentioned, the verb after thou is in its root form. I wonder why in current English subject verb agreement works for all if sb does sth sentences (but if the verb is be, there can be exceptions) including the conditional clauses with if. I see comments that thou delay should be revised as thou delayest, but I don't understand the differences. My speculation is that delay is not inflected probably to rhyme with Conceal thee till the day. But let's boil it down grammatically. In EME both OK? Mean the same?
No. 2, if written in current English, should be

And therefore, if a man writes little, he would need to have a great memory.

Why did Bacon use subjunctive? He referred to a specific group, but the fact that whether the man has written or not is not clear. In current English, however, we only use subjunctive in if clause when talking sth that didn't happen or will not be likely to happen. I deem, perhaps the outline of subjunctive in EME is such a melange that even Bacon
got conflated; because we should only use a nonsubjunctive conditional clause (if sb does sth) here in current English. Maybe it sounds authoritative, but is if he do sth an alternative to mean if he does sth?
And I find the same still happens to current English. We don't see the if s/he do sth structure anymore, but can sometimes come across sentences like:

If John be found guilty, he should have the right of appeal.-- from the Internet


He protected the baby under his arms lest he be trampled by the mob.-- OALD

where the linking verb be is the remainders of such exceptions of subject-verb agreement.
My questions:

How can I tell the tense of such noninflected subjunctive if clause usage?

Is there the if sb do sth structure in current English?

The meanings: “if sb be” vs “if sb were/would have been/would be/were to be”(subjunctive usage) vs “if sb is/was/will be”(nonsubjunctive conditional clause) when in current English

If my assumption is right, then how did the EME writers distinguish the tenses when they were using subjunctiven in their writing?


Please point it out if anything poor is written; I don't want my post to be closed once more.
Thanks if you would explain this for me.

Thou is second person and he is third person. The pronouns aren't interchangeable. Did you look up "thou" in a dictionary? What did you find?

Do you mean 'is it common'? Note that Emily Brontë didn't speak Early Modern English - thou is used to give the language a 'poetic' flavour. I think it should correctly be if thou delayest.

I've removed your PS because that should appear on ELU Meta or even Main Meta if it affects more than just this site.

You can find a partial answer at this duplicate question.

subjunctiveness is not a thing in English. https://grammarianism.wordpress.com/2015/05/21/does-english-have-a-subjunctive/

@Lambie: This question is in part about 17th century English, in which subjunctiveness was most certainly a thing.

@PeterShor I can read. It's just subjunctive. No need for the ness at all.

@Lambie -ness removed. Thanks.

This certainly seems a duplicate of the linked question but it's hard to judge. Maybe you could have a look and tell us. Note that the subjunctive in English was tenseless and uninflected so asking about tenses is misconceived.

(1846) by Emily Bronte - this is NOT eME
